# Multiple boolean values in if else statement is always false in Java

Tags: java, spring, boolean-logic

I am stuck to this method because of the if else condition says that

- `Condition usersInSales && usersInPayments is always false`
- `Condition usersInSales && usersInLoans is always false`
- `Condition usersInPayments && usersInLoans is always false`

I tried different condition combinations and added the false values to try resolve it but it didn't help. Please can I have some help? Thanks in advance

```
private List<UserResource> usersFilteredByDepartment(List<UserResource> users, boolean usersInSales, boolean usersInPayments, boolean usersInLoans) {

        if (usersInSales) {
            return getUsersInSales(users);
        } else if (usersInPayments) {
            return getUsersInPayments(users);
        } else if (usersInLoans) {
            return getUsersInLoans(users);
        } else if (usersInSales && usersInPayments) {
            return Stream.concat(getUsersInSales(users).stream(), getUsersInPayments(users).stream()).distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());
        } else if (usersInSales && usersInLoans) {
            return Stream.concat(getUsersInSales(users).stream(), getUsersInLoans(users).stream()).distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());
        } else if (usersInPayments && usersInLoans) {
            return Stream.concat(getUsersInPayments(users).stream(), getUsersInLoans(users).stream()).distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());
        } else return users;
    }
```

Comment: A necessary condition for the `if (usersInSales && usersInPayments)` branch to run is that the `if (usersInSales)` check failed. But if that failed, `userInSales` is false, so `usersInSales && usersInPayments` must be false as well. Did you mean to check `usersInSales && usersInPayments` _first_?

Comment: Move the `if` statements which contain two boolean conditions to the **top** of the `if` chain.

Comment: @Angge Check my updated answer. It may be that you don't need all those if else checks in your code.

Comment: Thanks everyone, I have reversed the logic and it worked well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have **two** solutions.

1. Reorder your conditions, as others have shown.  In your code by time you hit the `&&` statements you have already dealt with the cases when one half is true.  The `&&` (two clauses) is more restrictive than a single clause.
2. Alternatively, **put the double clauses inside the previous ifs.**

   ```
    if (usersInSales) {
        return getUsersInSales(users);
    } else if (usersInPayments) {
        return getUsersInPayments(users);
    } else if (usersInLoans) {
        return getUsersInLoans(users);
    } else if (usersInSales && usersInPayments) {
        return Stream.concat(getUsersInSales(users).stream(), getUsersInPayments(users).stream()).distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());
    } else if (usersInSales && usersInLoans) {...
   ```

becomes

```
    if (usersInSales) {
        if (usersInPayments) { // Nested if is like && operator.
            return Stream.concat(getUsersInSales(users).stream(), getUsersInPayments(users).stream()).distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());
        } else {
            return getUsersInSales(users);
        }
    } else if (usersInPayments) { ...
```

This is a little more efficient and I think generally preferable.

Answer (score 3):

```
if (usersInSales) {
        return getUsersInSales(users);
    } else if (usersInPayments) {    ---> You get here when userInSales = false
        return getUsersInPayments(users);
    } else if (usersInLoans) {  --> You get here when usersInSales = false && usersInPayments = false
        return getUsersInLoans(users);
    }  else if () {  --> You get here when usersInSales = false && usersInPayments = false && usersInLoans = false. No use in comparing what you compare here. It will be always false as it reports to
     }
```

Hope you now can figure your way out

You could try to check first the most specific constraints and then in the end move to more general constraints.

```
if (usersInSales && usersInPayments) {
        return Stream.concat(getUsersInSales(users).stream(), getUsersInPayments(users).stream()).distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());
    } else if (usersInSales && usersInLoans) {
        return Stream.concat(getUsersInSales(users).stream(), getUsersInLoans(users).stream()).distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());
    } else if (usersInPayments && usersInLoans) {
        return Stream.concat(getUsersInPayments(users).stream(), getUsersInLoans(users).stream()).distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());
    } else if (usersInSales) {
        return getUsersInSales(users);
    } else if (usersInPayments) {
        return getUsersInPayments(users);
    } else if (usersInLoans) {
        return getUsersInLoans(users);
    } else return users;
```

Checking your workflow however IMO your method would have more sense without all those if, else checks. **Just this could be enough**

```
 private List<UserResource> usersFilteredByDepartment(List<UserResource> users, boolean usersInSales, boolean usersInPayments, boolean usersInLoans) {
    
     return Stream.concat(
usersInPayments? getUsersInPayments(users).stream(): Stream.empty(),
usersInLoans? getUsersInLoans(users).stream(): Stream.empty(), 
usersInSales? getUsersInSales(users).stream(): Stream.empty()
).distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());
    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider your logic: you first check `usersInSales`, and return if it's true. Then you check `usersInPayments` and return if it's true. So when you then check `usersInSales && usersInPayments`, both will be false because you already handled the cases when either of them are true.

You need to change your logic so you handle the conditions additive instead of exclusively.

Answer (score 1):

your last 3 conditions will never run. because one of your first 3 conditions will already be true. To fix this you need to reverse the order of your conditions, try this:

```
if (usersInSales && usersInPayments) {
    } else if (usersInSales && usersInLoans) {
    } else if (usersInPayments && usersInLoans) {
    } else if (usersInSales ) {
    } else if ( usersInLoans) {
    } else if (usersInLoans) {
    } else return users;
```